# Are there any ready-to-use map controls for wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary

I know microsoft provides a bing map control.
And ESRI has a map control for wp7.

Are there any other map controls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What other sort of Map control do you want? The Bing Maps control is highly extensible allowing you to create tile sources for all sorts of other mapping data. For example you can use it to render Google Sky tiles:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/02/google-sky-on-windows-phone-7/

Comment: I am hoping for a map control that renders custom vectors and allows users to set styles for vectors.

Comment: That sounds entirely possible with the Bing Maps control. You can render vectors onto the map surface: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/MapBezier.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know that ThinkGeo are planning on releasing their mapping control for Windows Phone but I'm not sure when.

I also need something that can display tiles link Bing but also shape files from ESRI.

Have a look at the bottom of [this thread](http://gis.thinkgeo.com/Support/DiscussionForums/tabid/143/aff/12/aft/8817/afv/topic/Default.aspx)

Comment: You can vote up the request for a Windows Phone 7 client here http://helpdesk.thinkgeo.com/EnhancementTracker

Comment: Yes, I know that page. Actually, I use to be one of those guys who answer questions in the forum. Now I am working on other stuff :)

Comment: So you work for ThinkGeo? If so can you hurry them along with the WP7 client please! I need it like yesterday.

Comment: Bingo. It's still a rough plan now, so it's hard to say when it's gonna be released.